# Flip a boolean value in a simple way javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean

Given boolean value `completed = false` how do I flip it back and forth? I could of course do something like this:

```
if (completed) {
    completed = false
} else {
    completed = true
}
```

But that feels hacky and too long. Is there any slick and cleaner way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: `completed = !completed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you declared variable with `let` or `var`, so that you can reassign the value :

`completed = !completed`

Comment: What does `let` or `var` have to do with it?

Comment: Could be a function argument also

Comment: @Ivar if you don't use `let` or `var` and use `const` then you are not allowed to reassign the variable.

Comment: I see what you mean now. That might be worth to mention explicitly. You can also not declare your variable at all (it becoming an implicit global variable), in which case `completed = !completed` will still work without any issue. (Hence my previous question.)